# Programmatically remove an object array, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I'm trying to programmatically remember an object array but I'm lacking skills and I don't seem to find answers on the web either.

So, I want to be able to, while drawing a cardObj, to remove its reverse(upsidedown) alternative. Note that I wanna do the same if the reverse version is drawer first - remove the upright one from the deck.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Cardz Exerz!</title><link href="i5Cascade.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><header><div class="headerT"><h1>EXERZ!</h1></div></header><body><div><h2>Past, Present & Future<br>Spread</h2></div><div id="carpet"><div id="cardPPFBox"><table><tr><th>PAST</th><th>PRESENT</th><th>FUTURE</th></tr><tr><th><button class="drawBtn" id="btnPast" onclick="drawCard(&quot;imgPast&quot;)"><img class="drawImg" id="imgPast" src="data/backOfCard.jpg"></button></th><th><button class="drawBtn" id="btnPresent" onclick="drawCard(&quot;imgPresent&quot;)"><img class="drawImg" id="imgPresent" src="data/backOfCard.jpg"></button></th><th><button class="drawBtn" id="btnFuture" onclick="drawCard(&quot;imgFuture&quot;)"><img class="drawImg" id="imgFuture" src="data/backOfCard.jpg"></button></th></tr></table></div></div><script>// -----------JAVASCRIPT--------------//
      
      
      // CARDS OBJECT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
      let cardObj = [
      {name: "0_Fool", imgUrl: "data/0_Fool.jpg"},
      {name: "0_Fool_R", imgUrl: "data/0_Fool_R.jpg"}, 
      //{name: "1_Magician", imgUrl: "data/1_Magician.jpg"}, 
      //{name: "1_Magician_R", imgUrl: "data/1_Magician_R.jpg"}, 
      ];
      //--- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
      
      
      //SHUFFLE CARDS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
            function shuffle(array){
                    let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;
                
                        while(currentIndex != 0){
                            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
                            currentIndex--;
                    
                            [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
                        }
                        return array;
                         
            };
                shuffle(cardObj);
      //--- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
      
      
      //DRAW ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
      function drawCard(id){
      if(cardObj.length === 0){
      return;
      }
      
      
      
      let castCard = document.getElementById(id);
      
      
      let card = document.createElement('img');
      card.setAttribute('src', cardObj[0].imgUrl);
      card.setAttribute('height', '272');
      card.setAttribute('width', '185');
      card.innerHTML = cardObj[0].imgUrl;
      
      
      
      if(castCard.id === 'imgPast'){
      document.getElementById("btnPast").replaceChild(card, castCard);
      }else if(castCard.id === 'imgPresent'){
      document.getElementById("btnPresent").replaceChild(card, castCard);
      }else if(castCard.id === 'imgFuture'){
      document.getElementById("btnFuture").replaceChild(card, castCard);
      }
      
      if(cardObj[0].name === cardObj[0].name){
                        cardObj = cardObj.filter(function(f) {return f !== cardObj.name + "_R"});
           
                    }
      
      cardObj.shift();
      
      return false;
      }
      //--- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Not Remember at the beginning of the sentence but REMOVE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite confused about your question here but I'll assume what you want is to remove the "opposite" element of the array depending on the card that's drawn.

```js
let cardObj = [
  {name: "0_Fool", imgUrl: "data/0_Fool.jpg"},
  {name: "0_Fool_R", imgUrl: "data/0_Fool_R.jpg"}, 
  {name: "1_Magician", imgUrl: "data/1_Magician.jpg"}, 
  {name: "1_Magician_R", imgUrl: "data/1_Magician_R.jpg"}, 
];
function drawCard(id){
  if(cardObj.length === 0) return;

  // assuming that all 'reverse' cards end with '_R' and that 'id' is the 'name'
  const isReverse = id.endsWith('_R');

  // construct opposite card ID
  const oppositeCardID = isReverse ? id.substring(0, id.lastIndexOf('_')) : (id + '_R');

  // Find opposite card index in the array
  const oppositeCardIndex = cardObj.findIndex(card => card.name == oppositeCardID);

  if (oppositeCardIndex < 0) return; // opposite card not found

  // Remove opposite card from deck
  cardObj.splice(oppositeCardIndex, 1);
}

console.log("Cards before drawing:", JSON.stringify(cardObj));
console.log("Drawing card 1_Magician");
drawCard("1_Magician");
console.log("Cards after drawing:", JSON.stringify(cardObj));
```

Comment: @DavidDavid please mark the answer with the green checkmark if it helped.

Comment: Sorry I was rushing.. its not working after all.

Comment: @DavidDavid the code does what I wrote above, if you have a different use-case then you need to explain it otherwise I can't read your mind

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I'm not used to this. I want it to draw one card into the Dom. The drawCard(id) function is a variable element in the Dom in which I can invoke the drawCard().

Comment: So when I click a button the card appears in the Dom! But it is not filtering the cards in the cardObj array object. Like I said, I need it to remove the upsidedown or upright version of the card when it as already been drawn. Been the upsidedown version the cardObj.name which ends with '_R'

Comment: Cause they are the same card. One upright, the other downside. It's a tarot deck.

Comment: Maybe I can send the all folder with html and css to better understand. Cause I wasn't able to put all the code in the question because of errors it said, although it works perfectly on with brackets

Comment: I have just made an update to the answer with a proper code snippet, if you click on "Run" you can see the list of cards is updated accordingly when drawing "1_Magician" it's opposite ("1_Magician_R") is removed from the list. 

Now I feel like your problem is that you don't understand that you need to redraw the list of cards after a card is drawn maybe ?

Comment: 0_Fool and 0_Fool_R is the same card! Therefore, if in the array object, 0_Fool(object) is cast/drawn into the Dom, 0_Fool_R(object) must be deleted, since in a deck of tarot there is only one Fool card but can be either draw upright or downside.

Comment: Sorry if I'm having trouble to explain

Comment: And the code does exactly that, if you draw `0_Fool` it will delete `0_Fool_R`, if you draw `0_Fool_R` it will delete `0_Fool`. If you run the code you can see it does that on the array. 
The cards that are "drawn on the screen" won't update automatically but instead need to be redrawn on the screen however. So whatever function/code you're using to draw the cards, you should call it again at the end of the function.

Comment: Ok, the code actually kind of work with when I change it a little bit. But after a few draws it doesn't remove the opposite card. I'm surely making a mistake somewhere, but I can't tell where... Also, when I try to put the exact code you've proposed it doesn't render the card into the Dom. Maybe it is some kind of order issue or scope.

Comment: "So whatever function/code you're using to draw the cards, you should call it again at the end of the function." How do I do that? Can you exemplify?

Comment: I figured it out. i finally put your stuff working! Thanks